# Is there any way to get roscore string using python script in raspberry pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, ros

I'm using Raspberry Pi for LaserScanner(Motor + Rangefinder/Hokuyo).

For the case of Rangefinder, I open 3 command window,

**#1 : roscore**

**#2 : rosrun urg_node urg_node _serial_port:=/dev/ttyACM0**

**#3 : sh /home/pi/hokuyo/lidarDemo.sh /home/pi/Desktop/Demo/Data lidar.txt**

where lidarDemo.sh :

```
if [$# -ne 2 ] 

then 
  echo '2 inputs'
  exit 1
fi

rostopic echo /scan|tee $1/$2
```

Then lidar.txt is saved until I close the terminal#3.

lidar.txt :

header:

seq: 16828

stamp:

secs: 1594386688

nsecs: 380816175

frame_id: "laser"

angle_min: -2.35619449615

angle_max: 2.35619449615

angle_increment: 0.00436332309619

time_increment: 1.73611151695e-05

scan_time: 0.0250000003725

range_min: 0.0230000000447

range_max: 60.0

ranges: [3.888000011444092, 3.888000011444092, 3.888000011444092, ...

intensities: [2673.0, 2663.0, 2652.0, 2673.0 ...

---

header:

seq: 16828

stamp:

...

Now, Can I get those strings of lidar.txt by using python script in real-time?

For example, test.py :

```
while(True):
    str = getRoscore()
    print(str)
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Is there any way to get roscore string using python script?  Can I get those strings of lidar.txt by using python script in real-time? Can you please explain what exactly you want to do

Comment: When I run roscore on terminal, for example, 'rostopic echo /scan', It shows lidar raw data as shown above (like header : \n seq : 16828 \n ...). I want to get those strings using .py script! as a function like str = getRoscore()

Comment: Sure, check the answer will do your job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to get realtime lidar data in python; you can write a python script which has a subscriber to /scan topic where you can process your data in real-time something similar to this,

```
    import rospy
    from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan


    lidar_message = None

    def lidar_callback(data):
        rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + " %s", data)
        lidar_message = data
        ##Execute necessary processing here..

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        rospy.init_node('lidar_node', anonymous=True)
        rospy.Subscriber("/scan", LaserScan, lidar_callback)
        
        ##Execute rest of the logic here...

        rospy.spin()
```

Comment: Thank you! it works. By the way, do you know a substitute of rospy.spin() ? If I use it, it works until terminal is stopped(there will be 'n' data). I need only one data of lidar. I tried rospy.sleep(t) command, I guess it is not proper to my case.

Comment: That is the expected behaviour of rospy.spin(). I updated code here, the subscriber is triggering when you have a new message. So added lidar_message variable where you can access least lidar scan message, do necessary processing inside the callback itself.